# django queryset filter by list - get elements of list that are not found

Tags: python, django, list, filter, django-queryset

Let's assume, there is a django model `Data` with a charfield named `hash` and a list of hashes called `all_hashes`. Now it is clear, one can use filter expression to get all objects in `Data` which are within the list of hashes by using the `__in` syntax like:

```
all_hashes = ['45df...','ab23...', ... ]
filtered_data = Data.objects.filter(hash__in=all_hashes)
```

So if one wants to know which hashes have been found one could just do

```
filtered_hashes = [obj.hash for obj in filtered_data]
```

And you can get the hashes, which have not been found, like

```
new_hashes = set(all_hashes) - set(filtered_hashes)
```

Of course you can also directy get `new_hashes` by looping one by one through the list of `all_hashes` and individually try to retrieve a matching object from database however this sounds like it will cause a lot of queries and should be avoided.

The question is - is there any more direct way to identify for which items in a list no matching object could be found - maybe something that looks like:

```
objects_existing = Data.objects.exist(hash__in=all_hashes) => [true, false, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

As possible solution, try:

```
objects_existing = Data.objects.annotate(hash_in_all_hashes=Exists(Data.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('id'), hash__in=all_hashes)))
```

Now you could iterate over `objects_existing`, like:

```
hash_in_all_hashes = [obj.hash_in_all_hashes for obj in objects_existing] => [True, False, ...]
```

Or:

```
hash_in_all_hashes_list = list(objects_existing.values_list('hash_in_all_hashes', flat=True)) => [True, False, ...]
```

Comment: I tried your snippets however they did not work as expected. To be honest I'm not fully sure, how annotation works, but it looks like you can only annotate what is already in the queryset. So if you loop over the annotated queryset all you get are the results of Exists for the elements which already are in the database, which are - of course - all true.